# FFMPEG does not have fps filter. How to fix it?

Tags: ffmpeg, thumbnails

I am trying to user fps filter to take thumbnails but it gives error:

> No such filter: 'fps'

I checked the list of filters using `ffmpeg -filters` and `fps` was not there.

How to install it or fix it? Any other way to take screenshot without fps filter?

Comment: In the future, when asking questions about ffmpeg, please always include the full, uncut command line output as well, not just a single error message. Thanks.

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477115/what-are-the-differences-and-similarities-between-ffmpeg-libav-and-avconv

Answer (score 3):

Probably you have an old version of ffmpeg, that does not have this filter. Please visit http://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html and install the latest.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
It not you that's it's the ffmpeg wiki that's out of date:
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video
show's fps.
Instead of fps, use the -r option

```
ffmpeg -i my_movie.mp4 -ss 00:00:10.000 -f image2 -r 1 img%03d.jpg
```

Comment: I don't see anything out of date about the wiki. Also, the `-r` option and fps filter often produce different results.

Comment: +1 [Here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#framerate) it says the filter is called `framerate` (eg. `filter-complex framerate=fps=30`), which does not work with `ffmpeg version 2.7.2-2+b1` and it complains that there is `No such filter: 'framerate'`. But `-filter-complex fps=fps=30` works for me.

Comment: filter_complex.